# Python, remove password from memory

Tags: python, security, memory, memory-management

Im storing some user raw_input as a variable in Python 2.7, the issue is that this is sensitive as it is the encryption passphrase for a cryptocurrency wallet.
Therefore I want to ensure that once the Python script is completed, there is no trace of the passphase left anywhere on the system.

Where passphrase is the variable, is this at the end of the program:

```
del passphrase
```

good to utterly remove all traces?

Comment: If you want to manage memory _the way you want_, you should probably switch to C. For example, you could write a C extension for your Python code.

Comment: since you cannot modify a string in place, you cannot make sure it is erased from memory.

Comment: you could immediately afterwards force garbage collection ( gc.collect() ) and then create many small objects to increase chance to overwrite it. Still, Python doesn't seem fit for this.

Comment: BTW if it's sensitive, don't show the text. use `getpass`: `pw = getpass.getpass("password")`

Comment: Thanks useful tips, this is a hobby project so security isnt really critical, I wanted to know for the sake of knowing

Answer (score 3):

No `del xxx` or implicit deletion (leaving the current scope) may not be enough to hide the previously stored value. Note that this may crucially depend on your OS and your Python implementation.

However I would advise not to roll your own security systems **unless you really, really know what you're doing** but rather search an already existing solution for whatever it is you want to do and use that. For example I'm not sure if either `raw_input` or `input` are suitable for cryptographical needs.

You may get additional help in [Information Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Clearly I really dont know what Im doing! Thanks for the response, this is a hobby project for now so the security isnt critical at this juncture, just trying to get more knowledge.  To be clearer Im using the passphrase to insert into a subprocess.call to allow the target program to do operations, Im not actually doing any cryptographic transformation on it myself.